# Oracle SQL - ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, select

whats wrong about this code ?
I am trying to display all data on Employee_ID & Salary column, nothing else. what am I doing wrong here ?

```
SELECT IN
    ('Employee_ID','salary')
FROM employees;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT employee_id, salary FROM employees;
```